# how to add one more attribute to select which is a custom attribute in product listing

Tags: catalog, adminhtml

I have a custom attribute added to my catalog.its is a select box

While listing catalog i want to show it filtered by that attribute.

In my `mage/adminhtml/block/catalog/product/grid.php` i have `_preparecollection` function

I am trying to add my extra filter to `_preparecolletion` from my custom module.

How to do that

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
            ->addFieldToFilter('my_custom_field');// i want to add this filter from my custom module
        // so that i don't need to touch my core files.
```

is it possible?

Comment: You can override the grid block in your module and change the _prepareCollection method. I know it's not the best way to do it but I don't think there is an alternative. There are no events that let you hook in the collection attributes.

Comment: i tried to override that, but its giving me errors

Comment: How did you try to override it? What errors is it giving you?

Comment: @JanTomka:i tried to override this in my custom module.but it is not working.but there is no error also

Comment: You said it was giving you errors. You'll need to provide more information about what you're trying to do and how. Could you update your question with as much details as you can.

Comment: @JanTomka:sorry for that comment.by saying 'error' in that i meant its not giving me expected output.there is no error, but it is executing the _preparcollection from the core module. ie: mage/adminhtml/block/catalog/product/grid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 
app/code/local/Company/Module/etc, enter this in your config.xml

```
<config>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_grid>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

In app/code/local/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

```
      class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
    {

        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            parent::_prepareCollection();
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('field', 'value');
            return $this;
        }

}
```

Comment: :Actually i figured it myself.Problem was with my cache.thanks for your time

Comment: better use events to add the attributes, instead rewriting the collection class.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to add a new filterable column in the product grid, it's really not clear from your question. Like I said, rewrites are not necessary in this case, but since you want to use a rewrite, here is how you can do it.

First, rewrite the product grid in your module. Let's say your module is called Company_Module. Under `app/code/local/Company/Module/etc`, enter this in your `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

This tells Magento you want to rewrite the grid block. For this example, I'll use Magento sample data for CE 1.6+ - attribute `color`, which uses options like in your case. You need to override 2 methods, `_prepareCollection` and `_prepareColumns`.

In `app/code/local/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

```
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('color');
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $options = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color')
                ->getSource()
                ->getAllOptions(false, true);
        $optionsArray = array();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $optionsArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }

        $this->addColumnAfter('color', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Color'),
            'width' => '100px',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $optionsArray,
            'index' => 'color',
        ), 'status');

        parent::_prepareColumns();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

By doing this, you get an extra column which is filterable. Hope I got your question right.

Comment: Actually it was the problem with my cache :( thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in a module already, using an event observer. I did some research back then and I couldn't find a "better" solution for it. Here is the module, in case you want to have a look at it: https://github.com/mzentrale/Mzentrale_ProductThumb

Basically, I defined an adminhtml observer which listens to `catalog_product_collection_load_before`, and it loads the attribute only for given handles (`adminhtml_catalog_product_index` and `adminhtml_catalog_product_grid`). Then I added the extra column using layout XML.

Comment: :I am not looking for any observer.I am trying to extend the function _preparecolletion with one more filter.is it possible

Comment: Sure, what kind of error do you get? I just tried it with Magento sample date, no problem there.

Comment: please see my question

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to do? I can't understand if you want the collection to be always filtered (in which case, I honestly don't think it's a good idea, because some products will never be there) or if you simply want to add another column to the product grid.

Comment: if you want it "hardcoded" you can make a rewrite and extend that core module. You just have to change the _prepareCollection function, the rest should work just like in the core file

Comment: @fmrng:I want to add one more filter to the product preparecolletion.For this i tried to override this function in my custom module.code i have posted in the question.but it is not working

Comment: @Soundz:Yes i want to change the _preparecollection function.for this i am overriding this function in my custom module.but it is not working

Comment: have you told magento to use the rewrite in your config.xml?